# Unable to join a table and view - type inference failed in the call to 'join'

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I want to inner join my table column `EmployeeAccess.EmpNo` to my view column `VIEW_HCM.EmpNo`.

```
public List<EmployeeAccess> EmployeeAccess4()
{
    var emp = from b in contxt.EmployeeAccesses
              join c in contxt.View_HCM on b.EmpNo equals c.EmpNo
              select new                     
              {
                  b.EmpNo,
                  c.EmailAddress
              };

}
```

I get error with `join`:

> The type of one of the expressions of this joint clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'join'.

Comment: All of the EmpNo are smallint.

Comment: No it's not. No null values.

Comment: What type is the View_HCM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your fields is `Nullable`. I'm not saying that you have null values, only that the **type** is `nullable`.

Add `.Value` to the `Nullable` field to join these (I just put it on both because I don't know which one it is without looking at your DDL):

```
 var emp = from b in contxt.EmployeeAccesses
              join c in contxt.View_HCM on b.EmpNo.Value equals c.EmpNo.Value
              select new                     
              {
                  b.EmpNo,
                  c.EmailAddress
              };
```

OR if you have access to Alter the column set the column to NOT NULL

Comment: Thanks no more error in join. But what code do I need for return type?

Comment: You are defining an anonymous object so the return type would just be Object